# how to solve subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: sql

I have data like this.
[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWrsf.png)

I want to show show top 10 spending(Earn Point) members during the time frame.
My SQL:

```
SELECT  MOBILE,SUM(VALUE) as speding FROM crm_transaction  WHERE MOBILE IN (SELECT DISTINCT MOBILE FROM crm_transaction)
```

Comment: Please tag with which database.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  MOBILE,SUM(VALUE) as speding
FROM crm_transaction  
WHERE MOBILE IN (SELECT DISTINCT MOBILE FROM crm_transaction)
group by mobile
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
select mobile, sum('value') as speding
from crm_transaction
where time_frame between '<time from>' and '<time to>'
group by mobile
order by speding desc limit 10
```

you need to change time_frame with actual name of column that stores time, change <time from> and <time to> to your desired time values.